# beginner swift sprite kit - node collision detection help (SKPhysicsContact)

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sprite, collision, skphysicscontact

I want a sprite to delete itself when touching another sprite. Right now when they touch, they just push each other.

I have this:

```
let alphaCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 0
let betaCategory: UInt32 = 0x1 << 1
```

I made the sprites dynamic and not affected by gravity

```
self.physicsworld.contactDelegate = self

alpha.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = alphaCategory
alpha.physicsBody?.contactTestBitmask = betaCategory
```

and

```
beta.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = betaCategory
beta.physicsBody?.contactTestBitmask = alphaCategory
```

I couldn't find anything in swift that made sense to me, but I think the problem is here

```
func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody: SKPhysicsBody
    var secondBody: SKPhysicsBody

    if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.BodyB
        beta.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

Comment: if contact.bodyA ends up being the beta sprite, the code you have will not fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should set your firstBody & secondBody to the order of their collisionBitMask:

```
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask 
    {
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }
else {
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
     }

if firstBody.categoryBitMask=0 && secondBody.categoryBitMask=1 {
      secondBody.removeFromParent()
}
```

This will prevent your sprites from colliding with anything (including each other).  Set this where you set the other BitMask properties:

```
alpha.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
beta.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = 0
```

Comment: Reference the following tutorial which has a section dedicated to contact events.  It does exactly what you are looking for... when two objects collide it removes one of them.  I personally prefer how the tutorial handles it.  I just included the logic.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Comment: Thanks, the collisionBitMask is very nice!

Comment: Yeah I saw that tutorial but I thought it wouldn't work in swift.

Answer (score 1):

This will actually cause problems as I found out last summer when working on a SpritKit game.  If you modify the scene's node structure during any of the SKPhysicsContact callbacks the results are undefined according to Apple.  What I was told after filing a bug on this was that you should never modify the scene Node structure from inside any of those callbacks.  Instead, Apple says to simply set a flag and then deal with the scene modification in your update loop where it's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
secondBody = contact.bodyB
```