# Swift: sprite collision detection without making physics bodies?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

Alright, so I'm fairly new to sprite kit and I'm working in Swift. I have 2 sprite nodes, `savior` and `chicken1`. `savior` has a physics body and this is how I set it up:

```
var saviorTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "1.png")
saviorTexture.filteringMode = SKTextureFilteringMode.Nearest

savior = SKSpriteNode(texture: saviorTexture)
savior.setScale(0.2)
savior.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.size.width * 0.5, y: self.frame.size.height * 0.2)
savior.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
savior.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
savior.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSizeMake(savior.size.width, savior.size.height))

        self.addChild(savior)
```

`chicken1` right now does not have a physics body:

```
var chickenTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "block1")

        chicken1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: chickenTexture)
        chicken1.setScale(0.75)
        chicken1.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width * 0.38, y: self.size.height * 1.2)
        self.addChild(chicken1)
```

I need to know how I can have collision detection (i.e. if savior and chicken1 touch, execute this) between these objects, preferably without making `chicken1` a physics body.

When I make `chicken1` a physics body, suddenly it becomes erratic and moves other objects around.

If there is not a way to do collision detection without physics, how can I make `chicken1` a physics body that is NOT affected by anything and just goes right through the other physics bodies?

EDIT**************

So I followed [beginner swift sprite kit - node collision detection help (SKPhysicsContact)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270504/beginner-swift-sprite-kit-node-collision-detection-help-skphysicscontact) and have:

1. changed my class to be a `SKPhysicsContactDelegate`:

   class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
2. Written the following:

   ```
       self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

       savior.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = saviorCategory
       savior.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = animalCategory
       savior.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

       chicken1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = animalCategory
       chicken1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = saviorCategory
       chicken1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 0

       func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

       var saviorPhysics: SKPhysicsBody
       var chicken1Physics: SKPhysicsBody

       if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask
       {
           saviorPhysics = contact.bodyA
           chicken1Physics = contact.bodyB
       }
       else {
           saviorPhysics = contact.bodyB
           chicken1Physics = contact.bodyA
       }

       if saviorPhysics.categoryBitMask == 0 && chicken1Physics.categoryBitMask == 1 {
           self.chicken1.removeFromParent()
       }

   }
   ```

I ran it and there were no errors, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using `categoryBitMask` and handling the collision yourself by responding to the `SKSceneContactDelegate`.

This way you can set different categories for different nodes and handle the collision between the different categories as you please.

**Tutorial:**

http://seodoa.com/2014/04/01/skphysicsbody-react-to-contact-but-not-to-collide/

Comment: I looked at that tutorial but its for objective C so I've been following this link, which modifies it for Swift: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26270504/beginner-swift-sprite-kit-node-collision-detection-help-skphysicscontact

Comment: it doesn't work. savior falls through another physics body that I needed it to collide with and chicken1 does not delete when in contact with savior.