# SpriteKit's didBeginContact can't be called

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skscene, skphysicscontact

I tested with a simple scene.

Func `didBeginContact` can't be called.

I have try to use `collisionBitMask` and `s1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: 100)`. The problem was persistent.

What can I do to fix it?

```
import SpriteKit

class Test2Scene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        physicsWorld.speed = 0


        let s1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: kImagePlayer)
        s1.position = CGPointMake(100, 100)
        s1.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: s1.size)
        s1.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 1
        s1.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = 2
        //s1.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 2
        self.addChild(s1)


        let s2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: kImagePlayer)
        s2.position = CGPointMake(100, 500);
        s2.runAction(SKAction.moveToY(0, duration: 1))
        s2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: s2.size)
        s2.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 2
        //s2.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = 1
        self.addChild(s2);

        print("view did load")
    }

    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("aaa")
    }
    func didEndContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
        print("bbb")
    }
}
```

Comment: And some stuff about implementing contact detection inside of `didBeginContact` method : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36246855/3402095 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/27389834/3402095 , http://stackoverflow.com/a/20604762/3402095

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find out the reason. Need use

```
s1.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
s2.physicsBody!.dynamic = true
```

Comment: That wasn't the reason (at least for the given code) because `dynamic` property is set to true by default https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsBody_Ref/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsBody/dynamic

Answer (score 1):

Your code is pretty much all wrong, but your offender is :

```
physicsWorld.speed = 0
```

From the docs:

> The default value is 1.0, which means the simulation runs at normal
>   speed. A value other than the default changes the rate at which time
>   passes in the physics simulation. For example, a speed value of 2.0
>   indicates that time in the physics simulation passes twice as fast as
>   the scene’s simulation time. A value of 0.0 pauses the physics
>   simulation.

So setting it to 0.0 pauses the simulation. Second problem is that your nodes are affected by gravity but you move them using `SKAction`. That way you are pulling the node out of physics simulation and you may experience weird behaviours.

Also I would recommend to read [this great StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34904564/3402095) about bitmasks and how they work / should be used.